# Converting boolean data type to bit in Java

Tags: java

I've been working recently on "How to import excel files into database's tables". In this case, I have a column with bit data type. Meanwhile in Java I have a variable with boolean data type. The question is, can I convert boolean data type into bit data type in Java then use the converted value to store it into the table? Here's the script i've been working on recently

```
boolean isDiscount = (boolean) nextCell.getBooleanCellValue();
statement.setBoolean(8, isDiscount);
```

Comment: There is no "bit datatype" in Java, at least not in the java runtime or as primitive.

Comment: _Here's the script i've been working on recently_ What is the problem? I assume you are referring to SQL Server [BIT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type, which, according to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15) maps to Java `boolean` primitive. I also assume you are using [Apache] POI to get values from Excel, so [getBooleanCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getBooleanCellValue--) seems correct.

Comment: Continuing from my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66719577/converting-boolean-data-type-to-bit-in-java#comment117941166_66719577), the code in your question seems correct. So what is the problem? Does the code not work? Are you getting an error? Is the wrong value inserted into the database table? Is no value being inserted? By the way, please confirm whether you are indeed using SQL Server database and [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said @Turing85 java hasn't any bit datatype.

Anyway, if I got well your goal, with bit data type in excel col, you mean 0-1 (0= false, 1= true). I suppose you mean that... (?)

Altought Java not use "bit data type", you could convert a boolean into a integer value [0, 1] and then write it in excel's cell

```
 private int funcName(boolean flag){
    return flag ? 1 : 0;
 }
 
 //Now write the integer returned into spreadsheet
```

Hope this is useful for your achieve :-)

Edit:
Notice that Java hasn't any bit data type, but **boolean** is represented in **memory** with 1 bit

Comment: This helps me a lot. I have figured out that I need to convert the boolean to integer then I must modify the INSERT query so the column with bit value can be inserted into the table. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Java offers a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) class that allows to compact multiple boolean values but it should be used when there are relatively large `boolean[]` to replace.

```
BitSet statement = new BitSet(16); // represent 16 bits

boolean isDiscount = (boolean) nextCell.getBooleanCellValue();

statement.set(8, isDiscount);
```

However, storing `BitSet` in the database (e.g. via `BLOB`) may get too complicated in comparison to mapping Java `boolean` to `BIT` type in SQL.